# How we can send body in wso2esb mail format

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am using mail transport and i have done the changes in axis2 file and my esb ruining fine with mail but my issue is its not sending properr format i wish to send body also
but its just sending "Subject"
my config like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="StaticMail"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="senderAddress"
                   expression="//mail/text()"
                   scope="default"/>
         <property name="Subject" value="Alert:Reading Out of Range" scope="transport"/>
         <property name="message" value="Response message" scope="transport"/>
         <property name="body" expression="//list/text()" scope="default"/>
         <header name="To"
                 expression="fn:concat('mailto:', get-property('senderAddress'))"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="message" value="Response message"/>
            <property name="Sender Address" expression="get-property('senderAddress')"/>
         </log>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

but its sending mail format like this only

Alert:Reading Out of Range as a Subject 
there is nobody for mail and one empty attachment with"noname"
how we can send a mail with proper body please let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using Script Mediator a sample is [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Converting+the+SOAP+Messages+to+Plain+Text+Mail)

Here is another example which sends the error message as the email body and error code as the subject. Here payload factory is used instead of script mediator.

```
<faultSequence>
     <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ErrorCode" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
     <property name="ErrorMessage" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>         
     <property name="messageType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"/>
     <property name="ContentType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"/>
     <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Subject" expression="$ctx:ErrorCode" scope="transport"/>
     <payloadFactory>
        <format>
           <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:text>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg expression="$ctx:ErrorMessage"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="mailto:youremail@gmail.com"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </faultSequence>
```

Comment: actually i tried with payloadFactory but its going to mail as attachment and soap body example <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><emailEntry><assetCode>faisal</assetCode><parameterName>faisal</parameterName><inputValue>0.0</inputValue><minValue>42.6000</minValue><maxValue>99.5000</maxValue><status>below the allowed range</status></emailEntry>emailEntry/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"> Message or argument like $1</ns:text>
Did you try with the above line. I tested it and working fine.

Comment: ya now its working i added ur code thanx a lot for splendid support